# Is this possible to use a different rootfs that the one kernel comes with?

Tags: linux, boot, linux-kernel

Here's the situation: I have a compiled `zImage` that comes with its
own `rootfs` that contains `linuxrc`. I can extract it using [this
script](http://forum.xda-developers.com/wiki/Extract_initramfs_from_zImage). I
would like to modify some startup scripts that are part of the
`rootfs`. I don't have a kernel source code that was used to produce
this `zImage`. If I had I could simply modify `rootfs` and recompile
it. I thought about using `NFS` and pointing to the remote `rootfs`
and using it instead of the included `rootfs`. I tried these options:

```
root=/dev/nfs rw nfsroot=/home/ja/test-app/ext ip=192.168.1.1:192.168.1.2:0.0.0.0:255.255.255.0:TEST::off nfsrootdebug'
```

but they just don't work - a default `rootfs` is started every
time. I see that it takes a bit more time for Linux to start but
nothing more. However, this set of options **works** when used with
another kernel that has no `rootfs` whatsoever and which crashes if
no explicit path to `rootfs` is given so I think that it's correct
itself. The problem is - **is it possible to override an *included*
rootfs, ignore it completely and use it a different one?**

**EDIT:** not possible it seems in this case as included `/init` which is automatically called by `linux` ignores `root=` parameters completely, just does its jobs and calls `/sbin/init`. It's a shame.

Comment: There is `noinitrd` kernel command line parameter. Maybe it will work? Is `rootfs` in your question is really builtin `initrd` image?

Comment: @siblynx: I tried `noinitrd` but it doesn't work, included `rootfs` (`initramfs`) is always called. Some people wonder whether it's still possible to ignore `initramfs`: https://lkml.org/lkml/2012/4/10/354

Comment: Can you access shell in that initramfs? Or what shows `cat /proc/cmdline` after boot? There is probably something always appended or otherwise added to kernel command line about initramfs.

Comment: Yeah, and that's a bad thing when you do not have kernel source code and need to cope with the provided binary :-( So if `noinitrd` does not work then there is no way. You'll probably need to fool the contained code.

Comment: Hm, I look into 3.18 source and `noinitrd` at least _should_ work. The code does checking.

Comment: @siblynx: unfortunately I cannot access shell - `/sbin/init` starts a `REPL-like` program that cannot be killed with `C-c` and `C-z`. I can only access this kernel's `rootfs` shell through another kernel using `nfsroot` and pointing to the `rootfs` in question but the problem is that there are many errors when loading modules because kernels are in a different version.

Comment: @siblynx: one more thing - does `noinitrd` ignore `initrd` or `initramfs`? This kernel has only `initramfs`. `kernel-parameters.txt` says that `noinitrd` `Tells the kernel not to load any configured initial RAM disk` but in `initrd.txt` I think they specifically talk about `initrd`.

Comment: Today anyone probably already uses `initramfs`. [Difference between initrd and initramfs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10603104/the-difference-between-initrd-and-initramfs). So I was wrong, indeed there is no effect of `noinitrd` with initramfs, looking in 3.18 code.

Comment: I implemented `noinitramfs` for my 3.18 custom kernel fork and I hope it can be merged mainline too, see patch at [http://lynxlynx.tk/cgit/cgit.cgi/sanelinux/commit/?id=ee2f52ccf4c65ffd11bc0117142ad738a93365f5](http://lynxlynx.tk/cgit/cgit.cgi/sanelinux/commit/?id=ee2f52ccf4c65ffd11bc0117142ad738a93365f5). It works for me.

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for your effort. The link you posted is not valid any more, can you fix it please? I'd love to see the patch.

Comment: Yes, I recently changed domain name. Here is a new one: [http://lynxlynx.ru/cgit/cgit.cgi/sanelinux/commit/?id=ee2f52ccf4c65ffd11bc0117142ad738a93365f5](http://lynxlynx.ru/cgit/cgit.cgi/sanelinux/commit/?id=ee2f52ccf4c65ffd11bc0117142ad738a93365f5)